# How do I change what is printed when a Jest test throws an Error?

Tags: jestjs

Basically, quite a few of my tests use some autogenerated code. And the autogenerated code often throws an Error with a meaningless message - but it has some other fields on it that are quite meaningful.

By default, when a test in Jest throws an Error, jest seems to print the error message. I'd like to add a different handler for a particular subclass of Error that prints the more meaningful text. This will help me determine why my tests are failing faster.

Any ideas would be great!

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the error message you want? What does it look like?

Comment: @slideshowp2: the error that is usually thrown has a field called "response" on it that I want to print. The "message" field contains "an unexpected server error has occurred". But what I really want to do is tell jest "if the error thrown is a subclass of ServerError, then print in this way..."